# What is causing my Nodemcu/ESP 8266 to reset?

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I am using a sensor similar to hall effect sensor to count the number of interrupts. After some random time, usually after it has been ON for 1-2 hours it resets and followed by random resets at random intervals.

```
counter = 0;
sampletime = 0;
lastrisetime = tmr.now()
pin = 2

do
  gpio.mode(pin, gpio.INT)

  local function rising(level)
    -- to eliminate multiple counts during a short period (.5 second) difference is taken
        if ((tmr.now() - lastrisetime) > 500000) then
        lastrisetime = tmr.now();
    end
    -- when tmr.now() resets to zero this takes into account that particular count 
    if ((tmr.now() - lastrisetime) < 0) then
        lastrisetime = tmr.now();
    end
  end

  local function falling(level)
    if ((tmr.now() - lastrisetime) > 500000) then
        -- Only counted when the pin is on falling
        -- It is like a sine curve so either the peak or trough is counted 
            counter = counter + 1;
        print(counter)
        lastrisetime = tmr.now();
        sampletime = lastrisetime;
    end
    -- when tmr.now() resets to zero this takes into account that particular count 
    if ((tmr.now() - lastrisetime) < 0) then
        lastrisetime = tmr.now();
            counter = counter + 1;
        print(counter)
    end
  end

  gpio.trig(pin, "up", rising)
  gpio.trig(pin, "down", falling)
end
```

This is the error I get on CoolTerm, also I checked for memory every couple of hours and you can see the results there.

```
NodeMCU 0.9.6 build 20150704  powered by Lua 5.1.4
> Connecting...
connected
print(node.heap())
22920
> print(node.heap())
22904
> print(node.heap())
22944
> print(node.heap())
22944
> 2. .print(node.heap())
22944
> print(node.heap())
22944
> ∆.)ç˛.ä‚¸ ã ¸@H7.àåË‘

NodeMCU 0.9.6 build 20150704  powered by Lua 5.1.4
> Connecting...
connected
 print(node.heap())
21216
> F.)ç˛.¶Ùå¶1.@H  .ÊÍ

NodeMCU 0.9.6 build 20150704  powered by Lua 5.1.4
> Connecting...
connected
H!à»©.ä‚D.ã ¸å¶H.åb‘

NodeMCU 0.9.6 build 20150704  powered by Lua 5.1.4
> Connecting...
connected
 print(node.heap())
22904
> print(node.heap())
21216
>
```

Thank you for taking the time to read this. Appreciate your input.

Comment: Is this resolved? If so please consider [upvoting/accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer(s).

Answer (score 0):

Possible watchdog timer issue.

In your interrupt service routine looks like you are waiting too much.

Better to remove timing operations from there, just set a flag and in another loop, check the flag status and complete your timing operations.

Answer (score 0):

> NodeMCU 0.9.6 build 20150704  powered by Lua 5.1.4

The first thing really is to use a recent version of the NodeMCU firmware. 0.9.x is ancient, contains lots of bugs and is no longer supported. See here https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/#releases

> lastrisetime = tmr.now()

The real issue is that `tmr.now()` rolls over at 2147 seconds I believe. [I learned about this](https://github.com/hackhitchin/esp8266-co-uk/issues/2) when I worked on a [proper debounce function](https://gist.github.com/marcelstoer/59563e791effa4acb65f#file-debounce-with-tmr-lua).

```
-- inspired by https://github.com/hackhitchin/esp8266-co-uk/blob/master/tutorials/introduction-to-gpio-api.md
-- and http://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=24&t=4833&start=5#p29127
local pin = 4    --> GPIO2

function debounce (func)
    local last = 0
    local delay = 50000 -- 50ms * 1000 as tmr.now() has μs resolution

    return function (...)
        local now = tmr.now()
        local delta = now - last
        if delta < 0 then delta = delta + 2147483647 end; -- proposed because of delta rolling over, https://github.com/hackhitchin/esp8266-co-uk/issues/2
        if delta < delay then return end;

        last = now
        return func(...)
    end
end

function onChange ()
    print('The pin value has changed to '..gpio.read(pin))
end

gpio.mode(pin, gpio.INT, gpio.PULLUP) -- see https://github.com/hackhitchin/esp8266-co-uk/pull/1
gpio.trig(pin, 'both', debounce(onChange))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do have a reliable source that sells the latest NodeMCU firmware installed? I tried to flash it but it didn't work and the ones I found only sell the old Lolin version

Comment: "I tried to flash it but it didn't work" - then you need (to learn to how) to fix that. It's not sustainable to order new dev kits whenever you need a newer firmware: http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/flash/